# What does "Metal based electronic transition" means?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, absorption, nanoscience

Recently I've been reading on the chiroptical activity of metal nanoparticles protected by biomolecular ligands, which have optical activity signals that are manifested ***in the metal-based electronic transition in the visible region***, implying an ***electronic coupling effect***.

Any idea what does these two concepts mean?

For what I have read it just that... electronic transitions in the metal nuclei, but I can't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like fancy chemistry talk for "metals are strongly absorbing in the visible spectrum". For example, in gold it is mostly due to transitions from 5d valence band to 6sp conduction band. It has nothing to do with nuclear properties. On the other hand, you may be referring to the local surface plasmon resonances of the metal nanoparticles.

Comment: And how can you relate that specific transition (or another one) to a certain signal in the visible region?
What about *electronic coupling effect*, what is it that is *coupled* ?